# How do I make the remix connect to the quorum network

Tags: remix, quorum

How do I make the remix connect to the quorum network?

I'm using the latest version of the examples/7nodes in vagrant.
I'm trying with this url: 127.0.0.1:22000
I'm trying to connect to the quorum by remix on windows.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use truffle to connect with Quorum chain and truffle will compile your remix code to.By using command truffle compile

```
   Steps are 

           1. $truffle init 
           2. Do your remix code in contracts folder 
           3. Put this code in truffle.js

          module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 22000, 
      network_id: "*", 
      gasPrice: 0,
      gas: 4500000
    },
    nodefour:  {  //node Four
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 22003,
      network_id: "*", 
      gasPrice: 0,
      gas: 4500000
    },
    nodeseven:  {  //Node seven
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 22006,
      network_id: "*", 
      gasPrice: 0,
      gas: 4500000
    }
  }
};
```

4.truffle migrate

Here is the full steps link https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/building-dapps-for-quorum-private-enterprise-blockchains

Hope you like it 
Thanks